# Classe HttpStatusCode não existe o código 207, 208 e 226

Tags: c#, httpclient

O que fazer quando a classe `HttpStatusCode` não existe o código **207**, **208** e **226** ?

Alguém já fez a pergunta no GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4382, me parece que não fizeram um "update".
Segue código:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync();
if ((int)response.StatusCode < 200 || (int)response.StatusCode > 226 && (int)response.StatusCode != 404) //[200,208] = HTTP OK
{
    //HTTP Response Not OK
}
```

No código acima só pode entrar no `if` quando é diferente da lista abaixo.

Segue a lista da família "Success":

> 1. 200
> 2. 201
> 3. 202
> 4. 203
> 5. 204
> 6. 205
> 7. 206
> 8. 207
> 9. 208
> 10. 226

Fonte da lista: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Respostas_de_sucesso

Comment: Qual sua duvida? se  HttpStatusCode não existe ou  como  valida-lo ? sua pergunta ficou muito vaga

Comment: @MarcosBrinner Se vier código `207`, vai gerar exceção certo ? Como posso tratar isso ?

Comment: @MarcosBrinner só pode entrar no `if` diferente de 200 até 226.

Comment: O que extamente está acontecendo e o que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo estou consumindo API que pode retornar os 3 códigos acima (207, 208 e 226). Olha na minha lógica, que está dizendo que só pode entrar no `if` diferente de 200 até 226, porem não existe esses 3 códigos, o que fazer ?

Comment: Ou seja, só pode entrar no `if` quando não foi da família "success" !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Successful** não é apenas o range que você apresenta, ele vai de 200 ao 299, você pode validar através da propriedade `IsSuccessStatusCode` da classe `HttpResponseMessage`.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync();
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //HTTP Response Not OK
}
```

[Referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode)

Comment: O seu problema é com o `StatusCode` com o tratamento da chamada assíncrona, você recebe um 207 como resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode também usar a biblioteca **System.Net**, ela contém um enumerador chamado **HttpStatusCode** e você pode comparar os resultados, ao invés de usar números mágicos.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync();
if ((int)response.StatusCode < (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
```